# Comparing boxplots with different sample size

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, skewness, small-sample, boxplot

Let's suppose somebody did an experimented to measure how high a plant can grow on different soils. The experiment has been repeated different times for the different soils, with some soils having e.g. up to 30 measurements and others as low as 8.

You are shown only a plot where the measurements have been collected in boxplots corresponding to the different soils. Some of the boxplots have a very low median, but with a large amount of outliers in the higher tail. Some boxplots (the ones with low sample size) have no outliers, have a larger median and present a wider distance between the 1st and 3rd quantile (i.e. these boxplots are higher and longer). Notice that the whiskers of these anomalous boxplots are lower than the outliers of the boxplots with the low median and large sample size.

The question is: based only on this plot, would you conclude that the plants grow differently in the soils with the higher boxplots?

My answer is no, because the boxplots with a lot of measurements have a lot of outliers in the higher tail, which means that the distribution of the data is highly skewed to the right. Now, if I have a lower number of samples, it is enough to have one outlier from this skewed distribution that the boxplot will be longer and with a higher median.
But I am not entirely sure...because on the other hand you can say that if you have a small sample, the probability to get an outlier is small and the median shouldn't be affected too much.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. Even though the question is presented clearly a sketch of the box plots might help.

Comment: Hi Cherub, thank you for the feedback. I don't really have the boxplots, but I tried to make a manual sketch of it. I hope it is understandable and not too confusing